# Can someone identify this plant

Tags: species-identification, botany

Growing in a garden in the philippines

Photo from above notice the unusual leaves
[image]

Photo showing bloom... In peak bloom...
[image]

Photo showing pod that plant produced at the same time blooms appeared
[image]

Comment: What is the word for the leaf structure - meaning secondary terminal leaf at the end of a "tendril"? The plant form somehow reminds me of a Nepenthes, but the terminal growth is a leaf not a pitcher.

Comment: @user22542 I thought this could be called "mucron" in French, but I don't know in English (from what I've found, "mucron" exists in English but has a different meaning).